# Using SSRS 2008 Report in CRM 4.0 Application

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, dynamics-crm-4

Is it possible to design a 2008 SSRS report and use it in a CRM 4 application.  2008 Has much nicer controls and report designer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is more dependent on the backing database.  If CRM is setup with SQL Server 2008 it will support Report Builder 2008 reports.  If SQL Server 2005, the reports will need to be built in Visual Studio 2005 with the Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) installed.  2005 reports can be easily upgraded to 2008 reports but 2008 reports are not backwards compatible and cannot be easily converted back to 2005 reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a SQL Server 2008 SSRS instance and use that for reporting while continuing to use SQL 2005 for the database.

Everything is explained here: [CRM and SSRS 2008 Integration](http://procentrix.com/Community/BrendenS/post.aspx?ID=6)